# Branching of WSP packages

Tags: solution-package

Ideally, I'd like to branch a branding solution base I have been working on into two distinct branding solutions. However, I know that the solution ID (along with other identifiers) of a WSP can only be registered within SharePoint 2010 once. A second installation of an already identified package will fail.

Is it possible to have multiple packages with the same solution ID on a single farm?

How do you handle source control of solutions when you want to have a test and dev version of the same solution?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think the real question is why do you have dev and prod on the same farm? Also, what source control system do you use?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a farm of 6 servers, and an isolated lab environment in vm. I meant to say dev and test (I have edited the question to reflect this), but really its more about the branching of a solution. I use TFS for source control. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have multiple solutions with the same ID on a farm. When you deploy a .wsp it will overwrite the previous solution package.

To branch your solution in TFS let me refer you to the [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Branching and Merging Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/). Here, we branch when we have a release to snapshot the code in time, and then precede to develop on a separate branch, so we can effectively maintain multiple versions of code. How you use branching is your prerogative.